# Adding cookie to request in kotlin ktor client

Tags: kotlin, cookies, request, ktor-client

To include a cookie in a request using Ktor, you can use [`public fun HttpMessageBuilder.cookie(...)`](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.request/cookie.html?_ga=2.141330554.910159530.1694169987-438749624.1689109880&_gl=1*ceupcv*_ga*NDM4NzQ5NjI0LjE2ODkxMDk4ODA.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY5NDE3NTE1OC40MC4wLjE2OTQxNzUxNTkuNTkuMC4w) function, as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://ktor.io/docs/http-cookies.html). However, this function does not directly accept a `Cookie` object. Is there a function in ktor to append request with `Cookie` object?

To begin with, I tried to solve the problem this way:

```
fun HttpRequestBuilder.applyCookie(cookie: Cookie) = cookie.run {
    cookie(
        name = name,
        value = value,
        maxAge = maxAge,
        expires = expires,
        domain = domain,
        path = path,
        secure = secure,
        httpOnly = httpOnly,
        extensions = extensions
    )
}
```

But it failed cause `cookie` fun has no `encoding` param.

Now I just copied code from HttpMessageBuilder.cookie(...) and new function looks like this:

```
fun HttpRequestBuilder.applyCookie(cookie: Cookie) = cookie.run {
    val renderedCookie = cookie.let(::renderCookieHeader)
    if (HttpHeaders.Cookie !in headers) {
        headers.append(HttpHeaders.Cookie, renderedCookie)
        return
    }
    // Client cookies are stored in a single header "Cookies" and multiple values are separated with ";"
    headers[HttpHeaders.Cookie] = headers[HttpHeaders.Cookie] + "; " + renderedCookie
}
```

It works, but I think that this functionality should be in the library itself and maybe I just didn't find it

Comment: Ktor put its cookie handling in a [separate dependency](https://ktor.io/docs/http-cookies.html). Add that and use the `HttpCookies` plugin.

Comment: In my case I need to work with multiple sessions at the same time, so it seems to me that the `HttpCookies` plugin will not help

Comment: The plugin allows you to provide your own `CookieStore` implementation. I haven't yet seen an use case that it can't cover.